# Continuing function after else

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

thanks in advance for the help!

I'm building a simple program; the idea is for it to periodically check whether a variable has changed and, if it has, do something and, if not, check again. Use case: show a graph derived from the user's current URL in their browser; if the URL is unchanged, do nothing, if it changes, redraw the graph.

I'm running into an issue; I want my function to keep running while the condition is met, and if the condition is not met do something else, but then keep running.

Here's my while function code; my IDE and reading are telling me that "continue" is not permitted here: is there another way that I can keep my function active? Conversely, please do let me know if this is a foolish way to achieve what I'm trying to do!

```
    while new_value != previous_value:
        #wait
        #do something
        #put contents of new_value into previous_value
        #update new_value from external source (e.g. URL from browser, which may or not be have changed)
    else:
        #wait
        #do nothing
        #put contents of new_value into previous_value
        #update new_value from external source
        continue
```

Comment: I'm don't know how often you want to check if the URL has been changed or what other code you have, but it sounds like you need to use event listeners.

I'm more of a JavaScript guy, so I'm not 100% sure how to implement them in Python, but what you're describing is a perfect use case for event listeners.  (And I'm sure they exist in Python as well.)

Basically, you have some sort of listener listening to the change event that occurs when someone changes the URL, so that when the URL does get changed, you can run some specific code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this for future reference!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a while loop to keep your program running, and then use an if/else statement within the loop. Then just use break statement to stop running the loop.

```
while True:
    if new_value != previous_value:
        # Run your code
    else:
        # Run your code
        # When I want the loop to end
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

that's an alright start. The while loop will stop if the values are identical which is often. Inside the while loop you can add an if statement for the desired result. While True keeps going until stopped.

```
while True:
    #wait for a couple of seconds
    if new_value != previous_value:
        #do something
    #put contents of new_value into previous_value
    #update new_value from external source
```

Comment: @OliverCox did you manage to fix your issue?

Comment: I did not! Thanks for asking!

Here's what's happening (sorry if you already read this):


1. The if/then branch works (I set them to print 'if' and 'else' respectively and tested with the browser. 2. However, the variables displayed by my IDE do not update in real time, only when I close the script. 3. And, most importantly, the if branch doesn't create the desired graph, no matter how much I navigate in the browser, but when I close the script, the last graph that would have been shown if it were working pops up. Any ideas?

Comment: It can be helpful to put a print statement for each loop: print(new_value, previous_value) to understand if they are correctly changing. And you can try to isolate different sections of your code. For example, instead of putting the contents into previous_value, you can just do a previous_value = 2 to force the value to be different. And that way you go through your whole code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ah, excellent, I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Strange, here's a sample from the output:

1: else #I've set it to print the branch first thing it goes down each branch

2: focus_domain = omc.fyi last_focus_domain = omc.fyi #and to print the variables at the very end of each branch, per your recommendation

3: else

4: focus_domain = bbc.com last_focus_domain = omc.fyi #here I navigated from omc.fyi to bbc.com, and the variables update as expected

5: if #no graph!

6: focus_domain = bbc.com last_focus_domain = bbc.com #as intended, as the variables differed we did the if branch, and set them as the same in the process

Comment: Sorry about that horrible comment: I can't find a way to preserve my line breaks!

Comment: Yeah, comments are a tad limited. Either way, it seems you have narrowed down where the problem is. you can just make a temporary script where you do_something(website1) do_something(website2) and see if it is the result you want. Fix that and then later work with the while or if statements.

Comment: Thanks for this! So I've already tried putting the contents of the if statement into a function and having the if execute that (is that what you mean?) Meanwhile, the contents of the if branch work independently as well, or am I missing your meaning?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the 'else' statement, when used like this, is being executed once your loop is already broken. As such there is nothing to 'continue' and your IDE is flagging a syntax error.

This is a somewhat obscure Python construct, but it (and the reasoning behind it) are well explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go) at 15m53s.

What you're probably meaning to do is this:

```
while True:
    if new_value != previous_value:
        # Do one thing
    else:
        # Do a different thing
    
    # You will need to specify an end condition,
    # or it will continue looping indefinitely.
    if exit_conditon_met:
        break
```

Comment: You and the other commenters converged on this approach.

However, I'm getting the following error:

1. The if/then branch works (I set them to print 'if' and 'else' respectively and tested with the browser.
2. However, the variables displayed by my IDE do not update in real time, only when I close the script.
3. And, most importantly, the if branch doesn't create the desired graph, no matter how much I navigate in the browser, but when I close the script, the last graph that would have been shown if it were working pops up.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Oliver, I think perhaps you might need to provide some more detail about your code, preferably with a good example of your desired input -> output. If your initial query has been answered I suggest accepting one of the answers that helped you and maybe making a new, specific question for where you are now. Just now it sounds as if your trouble is in the expressions assigned to your subsequent / alternative it's really difficult to give any advice without being able to see that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
while True:
   #wait some seconds if you need
   if(new_value != previous_value):
      #do something
   else:
      #update new_value from external source
```